# Require newly registered user to complete profile form after social media login

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a .NET MVC site that collects a user's profile information (age, gender, location, etc) in addition to the account login email and password at the time of registration. This is working fine. Now I want to add social media login functionality (Facebook, Google, etc), but after user user creates an new login I want to force them to complete the profile page before they can continue to use the site. I'm not sure what the best approach is to accomplish this?

Comment: What information do you use to determine that the profile is not completed?

Comment: Assuming you have some logic to check if a user is logged in/registered yet send them to registration page?  Use similar logic but checking for a field (multiple fields) that are missing in the user profile then if not filled out send them to registration page.

Answer (score 1):

Once the user finishes the login flow from external providers (Facebook, Google, etc.), he will get redirected back to your site to a page of your choosing.

This page can be a normal .NET MVC page with a form where you can apply the needed validations.